# How to allow empty taxonomy to be search in wordpress search

Tags: php, wordpress, search, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have created one taxonomy like taxonomy1 and it have many terms like term_1,term_2,...,term_n. Some terms doesn't have any post i.e., it count is 0 but i want to shows those terms in my search result.

For example, term_1 count is 1 and term_2 count is 0, so when i search term_1 then i get the result as expected but when i search term_2 then i get nothing found.

So the problem is that if i have any term then it should be show in my search result whether it is empty or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get empty 'terms' with [WP_Term_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) by allowing 'hide_empty' property set to false.

```
$args = [
    'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy',
    'hide_empty' => false
];


$terms = new WP_Term_Query($args);
```

Comment: Yes i know this,but i have to implement it in wordpress search form (search.php). i have applied pre_get_posts action_hook and there is one condition is_search(), so how can i implement this in my is_search() condition.